# When are new versions of Quicken released? Should I wait a certain period of time before upgrading?

Tags: quicken

I'm running Quicken 2009.   Quicken 2010 is currently available.

When does Quicken 2011 typically come out?   Do you all upgrade right away? Or do you wait until a couple of minor upgrades are patched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I upgrade every 3 years because that is when they stop supporting versions.  My needs are modest and I really only use the budgeting, statement downloads and registers, and those items have been working well for the past 6 years.

I don't see any reason to pay the $70 Quicken tax every year unless there is a new feature that really compels you.

Comment: Agreed, seems the new versions just get busier and busier without really adding any features that I would actually want.  Only reason I upgrade is that eventually they stop supporting automatic transaction downloads on the old versions.